# Boolean algebra - neutral elements

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am searching for the neutral elements of following Boolean expressions:
-NOT
-NAND
-NOR

The neutral element of NOR should be 0 (false) but the others? I think for NOT and NAND there are no neutral elements exisiting.

Thank your for your help!

Comment: Generally you would consider a neutral element for a binary operation (two inputs).  Then $a$ is a neutral element if $a*b=b*a=b$ for all $b$.  NOT is a unary operator, and so would not have a neutral element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation tables for NOR and NAND look like this:

$$\begin{array}{c||c|c} \mbox{NOR} &0&1 \\\hline 0&1&0\\ \hline 1&0&0 \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c||c|c} \mbox{NAND} &0&1 \\\hline 0&1&1\\ \hline 1&1&0 \end{array}$$

From these tables, we see that neither NOR nor NAND has a neutral element.  (The row and column of a neutral element would match the row and column headers of the whole table.)